# Email is not getting delivered for more than 100 people in .net mvc

Tags: .net, email, model-view-controller

I am sending an email in our .net mvc application. i have a list which has more than 100 email id and i am sending email in bcc, but it will send only 100 emails at one shot, not more than that. How to solve it?

Comment: This is probably a mailserver limitation. Why not send it in batches of 100?

Comment: could you guide me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of one mail to 500 addresses, send 5 identical mails to 100 addresses.

So split your list into groups of 100 (or less - whatever that mailserver accepts).
Prepare the mail, using the first batch as BCC. Send it.
Replace the BCC with the next batch. Send it again.
Repeat until all batches have been sent.